# Wolfram Engine on new ARM-based AWS-EC2 instances

Tags: raspberry-pi, wolfram-player, applicationserver

Is it possible to install the [RPI version](http://www.wolfram.com/raspberry-pi/) of the Wolfram Engine on the ARM instances of AWS? 
Otherwise WR could distribute a version of CDFPlayer for ARM, do you think they are willing to do it? That would give sense to the the idea of the "wolfram engine everywhere" of Wolfram standalone applications they are talking about.

Comment: Maybe this is better addressed directly to Wolfram.

Comment: I am not familiar with the technologies that you mentioned. I just wanted to note that the Raspberry Pi version is 32-bit only.

Comment: The link you cite includes the text "Email us about the Wolfram Language + Mathematica for *Other ARM Systems*" (emphasis added).  What response did you get when you reached out to them?

Comment: @Szabolcs, you're right, these new instances on AWS are arm64 while rpi is 32.